# How to use EL with p:panel header?

Tags: jsf, jsf-2, primefaces, el

I want to put a dynamic string inside a `p:panel header` just like using it with `p:inputText` for example `value="#{object.property}"` is it possible to do that ?

Comment: Have you tried using `<f:facet name="header">`?

Comment: if you are offended, just stay at home and leave people to ask, ask, ask and ask,

Comment: @Java Player: You can read Primefaces's document to solve that, time to receive answer is more than time to read, thank !

Comment: @JavaPlayer RongNK means that you have to **search by yourself, try something and learn** instead of just asking lot of questions about *how can I foo the bar*? Yes, there are some advanced topics like overriding PrimeFaces CSS selector, but this question in particular is from basic JSF knowledge, which looks like you have failed to  learned.

Comment: One vote down for revenge!! thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just use `<f:facet name="header">` facet within your `<p:panel>`:

```
<p:panel>
    <f:facet name="header">
        <p:inputText value=#{object.property} />
        ...
    </f:facet>
    ...
</p:panel>
```

Or, if you want to output some text there, you can use `<p:panel header="#{object.property}" ... >`.

Comment: Valid answer, but I just have seen so many questions of this OP that can be easily answered with a simple search on the net that I just posted the comment asking *what have you tried before posting your question here*?

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza Saw your comment after posting my answer. Of course that's a starter's question, and *sure* it's a duplicate. Mobile devices are bad at searching :)

Comment: I don't agree Luigi Mendoza comment. I have searched 'primefaces panel escape header' and I have only found this Q&A and I have found a solution to my problem. I will now create a new Q&A with answer because my question is a little different :-)